# Reverse a stack using only queue in Java?

Tags: java, stack, queue, reverse

I need to loop through the stack until it is empty, adding each element to the queue. Then do the opposite. Loop through the queue until it is empty, adding each element back onto the stack

```
public class Q1 {

    public static void reverseStack(Stack st){
    }
}
```

Here is my test:

```
public class Q1Test {

    @Test
    public void testQ1() {
        Stack st = new Stack(5);
        st.push("A");
        st.push("B");
        Q1.reverseStack(st);
        assertEquals("A",(String) st.top());
    }
}
```

I have been trying to do the Q1 code and never get it to succeed and always end up fail. Can anyone implement a methods as said above to make the Q1 test succeed please?

Comment: " never get it to succeed and always end up fail" - your method is empty.  Doesn't look like you tried anything.  What results do you get?

Comment: public static void reverseStack(Stack st){
        if (!st.isEmpty()){
        Object curr =st.pop();
        reverseStack(st);
        st.push(curr);

Comment: Ah, a recursive attempt. It seems to me that it will result in the same order as before, though. If your stack has B on top, you are taking B out, reversing what was under it, then puts B back on top again.

Comment: Are you using your own `Stack` and `Queue` class or some from `java.util`? (`ArrayDeque` serves nicely as both stack and queue.)

Comment: Put the code in your question not the comments.

Comment: I think you have already described what you need to do: take the elements from the stack one by one and add them to a queue. Then take each element from the queue one by one and add them back into the stack. The result will be that the stack is reversed. Could you please show us your attempt at doing this? Then I promise I will try if I can see where it goes wrong (if it does; let’s hope not). And I’m sure I won’t be the only one.

Comment: i don't know how to do it that why i asking , but i get the explanation that why i expalined it above on how to do it in words but not in coding tho

Comment: I am sorry, but Stack Overflow is neither the place to learn the basics — use your textbook and/or the tutorials for that — nor is it the place to have your code (homework?) written for you. Also, the code will depend on your queue class, which we don’t know, so even if we wanted, we could not write the code for you.

Comment: So what do i need to learn in order to this kind of thing? i try https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRcY2vIr-EQ and not work and i bought 3 text book for like £100 which didn't help one bit.

Comment: When the assignment (or what it is) says “adding each element to the queue”, have you got a queue class for that? Are you required to write your own? Have you got a `Stack` class or do you need to write one?

Comment: Yeah i have all those stack and queue class and they are very long. I suppose to use them to do Q1?  Because i already got the completed Test on Q1Test so i just thought i could use that to do the Q1?

Comment: The assignment was actually called implement a method that reverse a stack using "only queue".  Which i have no idea how to do it . i could reverse with a recursion,etc. Anyway i got the methods( in words) that i mention in the post to tell me how to actually implement a methods that reverse a stack using only queue so i was hoping can a least show me a example or something similar that demostrate a stack reverse with just queue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

Q1.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Q1 {

    private List<String> list;

    public Q1() {
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public String pop_front() {
        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            String front = list.get(0);    
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size()-1; i++) {
                list.set(i, list.get(i+1));
            }
            list.remove(list.size()-1);
                return front;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void push_back(String obj) {
        list.add(obj);
    }

    public String front() {
        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            return list.get(0);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return list.isEmpty();
    } 

    public static void reverseStack(Stack stack) {
        Q1 queue = new Q1();
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            queue.push_back(stack.pop());
        }
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            stack.push(queue.pop_front());
        }
    }
}
```

A Stack class:

Stack.java

```
 package com.dub;


    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Stack {

        private List<String> list;

        public Stack() {
            list = new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        public String pop() {
            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                String top = list.get(list.size()-1);

                list.remove(list.size()-1);

                return top;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public void push(String obj) {
            list.add(obj);
        }

        public String top() {
            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                return list.get(list.size()-1);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return list.isEmpty();
        }

    }
```

and now the test method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Stack stack = new Stack();

    stack.push("A");
    stack.push("B");
    stack.push("C");

    System.out.println("top: " + stack.top());

    Q1.reverseStack(stack);

    System.out.println("top: " + stack.top());

}
```

It prints as expected:

top: C

top: A